# Read text file data using Spark and split the data using comma - python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in below format.

```
abc, x1, x2, x3  
def, x1, x3, x4,x8,x9   
ghi, x7, x10, x11
```

The output I want is

```
0,abc, [x1, x2, x3]  
1,def, [x1, x3, x4,x8,x9]  
2,ghi, [x7, x10, x11]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I have tried 2 solutions provided and done the problem with little modifications. what I have done is by converting into rdd and then using map function.    rdd = spark.read.text(filename).rdd
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(number=str(x['value'].split(',')[0]), count=str(x['value'].split(',')[1:])))

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not in CSV format. CSV means a comma-separated text file with a fixed schema. The CSV for your data would be:

```
abc,x1,x2,x3,,
def,x1,x3,x4,x8,x9
ghi,x7,x10,x11,,
```

Note the trailing commas in lines 1 & 3, which are not in your data.

Since you have a text file that is not a CSV, the way to get to the schema you want in Spark is to read the whole file in Python, parse into what you want and then use `spark.crateDataFrame()`. Alternatively, if you have more than one file like this in a directory, use `SparkContext.wholeTextFiles` and then `flatMap` your parsing function.

Assuming you've already done something like `open("Your File.txt").readlines`, the rest is simple:

```
import re
from pyspark.sql import *

lines = [
  "abc, x1, x2, x3",
  "def, x1, x3, x4,x8,x9",
  "ghi, x7, x10, x11"
]

split = re.compile("\s*,\s*")
Line = Row("id", "first", "rest")

def parse_line(id, line):
  tokens = split.split(line.strip)
  return Line(id, tokens[0], tokens.pop(0))

def parse_lines(lines):
  return [parse_line(i, x) for i,x in enumerate(lines)]

spark.createDataFrame(parse_lines(lines))
```

Comment: Sorry data is not csv but the data is separated by commas and I want it separated by name and parameters. Could me help me by how to use flatmap for parsing it.

Comment: `flatMap` is only for the cases where you have lots of files. I updated the answer with example code.

Comment: Thank you, sir! This idea of creating a dataframe by a callback function is ingenious!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to generate first the id using `zipWithIndex` and then inside the map function take the first part of the string with `r[0].split(",")[0]` and the second with `r[0].split(",")[1:]`.

Here is the code as described above:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

lines = ["abc, x1, x2, x3",
        "def, x1, x3, x4,x8,x9",
        "ghi, x7, x10, x11"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(lines, StringType())
df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex() \
           .map(lambda (r, indx): (indx, r[0].split(",")[0], r[0].split(",")[1:])) \
           .toDF(["id", "name", "x_col"])

df.show(10, False)
```

And the output:

```
+---+----+-----------------------+
|id |name|x_col                  |
+---+----+-----------------------+
|0  |abc |[ x1,  x2,  x3]        |
|1  |def |[ x1,  x3,  x4, x8, x9]|
|2  |ghi |[ x7,  x10,  x11]      |
+---+----+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, lambda (r, indx) raises error as invalid syntax.

Comment: Hi there, could you paste your code please?

Comment: Sure @abiratsis 

    sc = SparkContext /

    df =          
    sc.textFile("/home/kubra/PycharmProjects/Recom_Data/october2020ItemList.txt") /


    df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex() \
           .map(lambda (r, indx): (indx, r[0].split(",")[0], r[0].split(",")[1:])) \
           .toDF(["id", "name", "x_col"])

It does not accept lambda (r, indx) as a typo.

Comment: what about `lambda r, indx`? Does the error still remain?

Comment: In this case the following error rises;

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'indx'
. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If data come in file, can implemented in such way:

1. Read file as CSV;
2. Add index column with "monotonically_increasing_id"
3. Select first column, and all remaining columns as array.

On Scala can be implemented in this way:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("non-csv.txt")
val remainingColumns = df.columns.tail
df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id).
  select(
    col("id"),
    col(df.columns(0)),
    array(remainingColumns.head, remainingColumns.tail: _*)
  ).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+--------------------+
|id |_c0|array(_c1, _c2, _c3)|
+---+---+--------------------+
|0  |abc|[ x1,  x2,  x3]     |
|1  |def|[ x1,  x3,  x4]     |
|2  |ghi|[ x7,  x10,  x11]   |
+---+---+--------------------+
```